# RoR environment in Ruby standalone script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment

I want to run a standalone ruby script in which I need my RoR environment to be used. Specifically, I need my models extending ActionMailer and ActiveRecord. I also need to read the database configuration from my database.yml. 
How do I go about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to change the shebang of your script from :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

to

```
#!/path/to/your/rails/script/runner
```

Et voilà, your script will be run with the full rails environment loaded. You can also run your script as `./my_script -e production` to have it run with the production database.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread:
[How do I run Ruby tasks that use my Rails models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293302/how-do-i-run-ruby-tasks-that-use-my-rails-models)

Essentially it boils down to:

```
require "#{ENV['RAILS_ROOT']}/config/environment.rb"
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to make it a rake task.

```
   # lib/tasks/mystuff.rake
   desc 'do my stuff'
   task :my_stuff => [:environment] do
     # do my stuff
   end
```

The [:environment] stanza loads the rails environment.