# What is the correct way to run a custom ruby script from inside the script directory from Rails application? (Production environment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scripting, production-environment

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335451/ror-environment-in-ruby-standalone-script)

I tried all of the answers from the above stack overflow post but none of them worked

When I replace the   #!/usr/bin/env ruby with the #!/path/to/my/script/runner and try to run

Rails returns:

/var/www/cmgmail/production/releases/20100810151610/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:76:in `establish_connection': Please install the postgresql adapter:`gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter`(no such file to load -- pg) (RuntimeError)
    from /var/www/cmgmail/production/releases/20100810151610/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in`establish_connection'
etc.  .  .  .

when I leave the original shebang #!/usr/bin/env ruby intact, no combination of commands work.

e.g.
script/my_script -e production returns:

/var/www/cmgmail/production/releases/20100810151610/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in `establish_connection': development database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
    from /var/www/cmgmail/production/releases/20100810151610/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in`establish_connection' ...etc

./my_script returns:
./my_script: No such file or directory (yet I verified the file is there)

is there something obvious I am missing?

I suppose I can make this into a rake task but this script runs fine in dev mode.

Comment: NOte: I do have this line at the top of the file
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment'
AND my script is in the script directory

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to run `chmod a+x my_script`. By the way, try running `script/my_script` with the `RAILS_ENV=production` environment variable.