# How does Rails know when to delete a record from the `sessions` table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

How does Rails know when to delete a record from the sessions table?

For example, if a user visits the website, a session record is created, but when the user closes the browser window, the server doesn't get any notification, so how does Rails delete records from sessions table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide your own implementation of session expiration, to my understanding.

[This API page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SessionStore.html) gives you a pretty decent answer to how that works. You create your database table with the extra attributes created_on and updated_at (and you get timestamps for free) and then you just create a job to expire them whenever you want by looking at the updated_at attribute.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285717/a-cron-job-for-rails-best-practices) has details of how to run a job.

Answer (score 7):

There are simplier ways:

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.delete_all(["updated_at < ?", 12.hours.ago])
```

You can call it after some Action in Controller and this piece of code kill all dead sessions.

Of course it is disputable technique, but the simplest.

[Full story](http://www.isnorcreative.com/blogs/39)

Comment: I'd really want to do something like that asynchronously, like from a cronjob.

Comment: This worked well, run through rails runner along with whenever gem to make it as a cron job.

Comment: We had a similar problem and wanted to get away from running this via cron, so we're experimenting with MySQL Events: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html.  Hopefully that helps others running into the same thing.

Comment: Here is the updated "Full Story" link regard using a datastore as a disputable technique. http://www.isnorcreative.com/blog/deleting-old-ruby-on-rails-active-record-sessions-using-whenever-and-capistrano  We use database storage for sessions when working with multiple web servers. It is a good solution as long as you keep stale sessions purged, otherwise, it bloats horribly.