# Automatically delete posts Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an app where users can decide when their posts will be deleted, but I don't know how to do it in Rails 3.

Comment: You will have to provide more info, like what authentication system etc...

Comment: I'm using Devise. It's a simple app. where Users just add fields: Name Price Description Deadtime

Comment: When to delete posts? Do you mean deleting records based on schedule (as in Deadtime field)?

Comment: yes, your are right, deadtime is a field according to which records will be deleted

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you will have to use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can inactivate a post rather than executing the database command "delete". If you inactivate, then you'll keep statistics and comments.

```
class Post
  attr_protected :published_on, :deleted_on
  belongs_to :user
  scope :published, lambda{ where("published_on >= ?", Time.now).where("deleted_on IS NULL or deleted_at < ?", Time.now)}

end
```

in your controller later:

```
@posts = @user.posts.published.paginate(params[:page])
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the posts to be automatically deleted on a certain date(time) and your users are able to set that date(time). To achieve that you must use cron jobs. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285717/a-cron-job-for-rails-best-practices) you can find more about it.

Another (real dirty) solution is to execute a method each time your app is accessed and look for the posts that needed to be deleted.