# rails-how to update attributes based on time/day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, update-attributes

How would you update attributes in your database based on the time of day or what day it is. I have three attributes energy, hunger, and happiness that I want to decrease by ten every hour but I don't quite know how to go about doing this. I know there are timestamps in the database but I don't really know how to use them. Also I want to change the players skills every day based on their job. So if you have this job, add 2 to intelligence every day. But I don't know how to add that 2 every day. I would love it if anyone could give me help on this problem. I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options:

- **cronjob:** You could setup your cronjob to access the database directly through a SQL script (probably the simplest solution out of all in terms of setup) or go through your rails application first (e.g. in case you need to run additional business logic before updating the database - you mentioned something about updating the database based on the user job). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285717/a-cron-job-for-rails-best-practices) for the latter approach.
- **Background task:** Take a look at [Starling/Workling](http://railscasts.com/episodes/128-starling-and-workling) or [Backgroundrb](http://backgroundrb.rubyforge.org/). You can use either of these to run a background task that could update your database at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common but fundamentally different ways of achieving this:

- During each request, simulate the amount of time which has passed since the last request. If a user makes two requests three hours apart, simulate three hours of time passing by subtracting 30 happiness (10/hour times 3 hours) all at once. This is less resource intensive, but requires a little more thinking on your part. It's not difficult for something as simple as "lower a value by 10 every hour", but more complex interactions are more difficult to model.
- Run a cron job which invokes an action in your program every hour, on the hour, to deduct 10 happiness from each account. This is easier conceptually, but involves a lot of overhead if you have many users, especially when some of them are idle for long periods.