# Rails polling RSS every 6 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss, polling

I am seeking advice on how to poll RSS with a given interval such as 6 hours.

The following code works, it reads and parses the feed and adds it to the database. It only adds new feeds. Here is the class method:

```
def self.update_from_feed(feed_url)
  feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse("http://feeds.feedburner.com/PaulDixExplainsNothing") #Example feed
  feed.entries.each do |entry|
    unless exists? :guid => entry.id
      create!(
        :name         => entry.title,
        :url          => entry.url,
        :published_at => entry.published,
        :guid         => entry.id
      )
    end
  end
end
```

How do I run this entire class method lets say, every 6 hours? I'm new to Ruby (and Rails), so any help would be appreciated with an example. I want to avoid running an external cron job if possible. I want it to run every 6 hours within the code if that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [A cron job for rails: best practices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285717/a-cron-job-for-rails-best-practices)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense to not use cron for this. This is what cron is for, it's in the name of the program.

If you don't like the cron syntax, that's cool, there's a gem called whenever, https://github.com/javan/whenever that gives a nice Ruby syntax for generating a cron job and a command that lets you do that.

However, for the love of god, do not try to invent a new way of doing this, unless you're adding some killer features. Use cron, move on.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I came across this earlier but I was rather confused. Would I just run the model with it? such as `every 6.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"       
end` I don't understand the runner part, MyModel would be the name of the model, but what is the .some_process? Would that be .update_from_feed?

Comment: That's a possibility. I tend to stick to using rake tasks, because they're easier to understand. Write a simple rake task that loads the environment and then executes the class method. This way, you can even dynamically load which URLs you want Feedzirra to hit and you can loop over them, all in the background and not using up the resources that serve the website to users.