# how to create a delayed job in rails to run at one year interval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks, delayed-job

I want to create a delayed job which will run after one year interval continuously? That is at particular date on every year. How can i achieve this using delayed job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [delay-jobs gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), so you can add time of running as params as the following:

```
Notifier.delay(run_at: 1.years.from_now).signup(@user)
```

See [RailsCasts for delay-jobs](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job)

For run this code as daily tasks, you need to read [Resque gem](https://github.com/resque/resque), [resque-scheduler gem](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler), and see [helpful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475296/how-to-run-daily-tasks-scripts-in-a-rails-project)

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it will run only once? I want to run it at a particular date on every year.

Comment: I update my solution to make daily task for running the previous code, I hope it'll be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby) is good screenacast

Comment: I agree with @grosefaid.  You don't want to use Delayed Job for this.  Use a gem like `whenever`, which is a nice ruby abstraction for `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler). From the documentation you'll have a lot of ways to schedule your tasks:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

# ...

scheduler.in '10d' do
  # do something in 10 days
end

scheduler.at '2030/12/12 23:30:00' do
  # do something at a given point in time
end

scheduler.every '3h' do
  # do something every 3 hours
end

scheduler.cron '5 0 * * *' do
  # do something every day, five minutes after midnight
  # (see "man 5 crontab" in your terminal)
end
```

Also, be aware that if you kill you application, it will loose the schedule, so it's advised to save the information on database and retrieve it on startup.