# How to add particular task in background job rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

This is my rails controller#action

```
Class ReportController < ApplicationController

  def monthly_report

   end

end
```

I need to add this particular action(monthly_report)  in background job. I don't know how to do this using delayed_job gem?

Please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options.

May be you can find details here => [A cron job for rails: best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285717/a-cron-job-for-rails-best-practices)

Also give a try with `whenever`. http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby