# Sending automatic mails in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, cron

In my rails application, users can subscribe to some events. I'd like to send a mail to the user 24 hours before the begining of the the event.

I'm not sure how to implement that. A rake task ? Is there some gems or some best practices to follow ?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I guess that my cron must be run every minute to get each event that starts in 24 hours. But if the cron stops, or it takes more than a minute, I can't skip some emails. In the other way, how can I be sure I'm not sending the same email twice ?

Comment: You didn't try to enter some of your words into google, did you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A cron job for rails: best practices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285717/a-cron-job-for-rails-best-practices)

Comment: Of course I did, but it's not the same problem. Please try to understand before downvoted! Maybe I must clarify my question. It's not a simple cron. My cron must be run every minute to get each event that starts in 24 hours. But if the cron stops, or it takes more than a minute, I can't skip some emails. In the other way, how can I be sure I'm not sending the same email twice ?

Comment: Updated my answer to take this comment into account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

for sending mail and

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised

for using whenever to set up a cron to call your mailer

EDIT: Just saw your comment. In that case I would look at using something like resque-scheduler or the equivalent with sidekiq:

https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler

then you can do things like this:

```
Resque.enqueue_at(24.hours.from_now, SendFollowUpEmail, :user_id => current_user.id)
```

sidekiq example:

```
FollowUpEmailer.perform_in(24.hours.from_now, current_user.id)
```

Comment: I already use sidekiq. In fact, I don't really need a cron for that. I just need to add your line in a after_create, right ?! Is there a way to cancel the email if the user unsubscribe the event ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way see: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/pull/257, the last comment there Mike says that your job should check to see if it should be sent. In that case I'd just have: send_email if user.subscribed? in my job

Comment: Should be easy to implement. Thanks a lot! The only down side I see is if my server crashes or is rebooted, I lose all the messages in my sidekiq queue...

Comment: Oops, read a little further on that link I put up and there is an API to remove jobs now. However, in your case, I'd probably still go with what I suggested.

Comment: You can make redis save to disk from time to time to minimize the impact of a crash: http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/pull/257

This will help you to solve automatic mailing system in scheduled time!