# Ruby on Rails Cron Job Example

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi um quite new to rails platform and um looking for a rails cron job scheduling tutorials . I ve gone through with tutorials use whenever and the other scheduling gems , but um looking for a core ruby implementation with the cron tab on rails . Thank you in advance

Comment: cron is cron, nothing related with rails.

Comment: Hey you can schedule cron jobs within rails app. Use "whenever" gem. its a simple and good gem. See my answer. It may help you. I am using the same gem in my application.

Comment: @xdazz yah cron is cron question was asked for an implementation in ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Railscasts has a [decent tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby) on using Cron.

**EDIT**

If you would like an example of how it was implemented from scratch, you could have a look at how the Whenever Gem is implemented [here](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: Hi I want to learn from the scratch without whenever . Thank you

Comment: Ok well I suppose you could look at  the source code (https://github.com/javan/whenever) for the Whenever gem, and that might give you a good starting point seeing as it's doing what you want to do from scratch...

Comment: No problem, I've edited the answer to better reflect what the original question was

Answer (score 2):

To set cron jobs, you can depend the help of a simple gem named [WHENEVER](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Its very easy to implement. Go for it.

Comment: Hi I want to learn it from the hard way without whenever . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Many people are against this approach (see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285717/a-cron-job-for-rails-best-practices)) but triggering your application's action with curl/wget from a cron job may be a quick-and-easy solution for periodic tasks.

You just have to keep a few things in mind:

- Keep execution time of your action low (as it will block your application just like a regular web request would do)
- Make sure that you do not allow anyone to trigger the action (by using IP restrictions, secret tokens or other security measures)

For more information on this topic, I have written [an article](http://www.relativkreativ.at/articles/a-way-to-trigger-a-rails-action-from-a-cron-job-you-may-not-have-thought-about) about it.

Answer (score 1):

For minimal setup of "cron-like" tasks in "core" rails/ruby, I created https://github.com/Ebbe/arask

No need to install anything (other than the gem) or setup anything outside of rails.

Add `gem 'arask'` to your Gemfile, run `bundle install`, `rails generate arask:install` and `rails db:migrate`.

Now you can setup your tasks in the file config/initializers/arask.rb:

```
arask.create task: 'send:logs', cron: '0 2 * * *' # At 02:00 every day
arask.create script: 'puts "IM ALIVE!"', interval: :daily
arask.create task: 'my:awesome_task', interval: :hourly
arask.create task: 'my:other_awesome_task', interval: 2.hours
```

The tasks will automatically run if the server is running.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `rufus-scheduler`, It uses threads to execute functions scheduled. Very simple to configure. just 3 steps:

1 - Add gem `gem 'rufus-scheduler', '~> 3.6'`

2 - Create file `config/initializers/scheduler.rb`

3 - Programming schedule in scheduler.rb:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
s = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton
s.every '5s' do
    #do every 5 seconds exec this code
    puts "WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"
end

s.in '2d' do
  # every 2 days exec this
  puts "Now it's me"
end
```

For more doubts : https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

Comment: Good solution. Just one annotation, `scheduler` should be updated with `s` in line 8.

Comment: thanks dude! I did not notice this. thank you very much for up vote!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use and external free service to outsource cronjobs http://guardiano.getpeople.in

DISCLAIMER: I made it