# Files storing with Jquery FIle Upload (or other plugins )

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload, asyncfileupload

I am trying to make Jquery File Upload to work and I'd like an advice about storing the files and particularly I am concerned about the situation when a user chooses a few files so they get downloaded to the server and then user just closes the browser or the tab or whatever, so I have extra files on my server which wont be used and therefore I will have to come up with something to remove these extra files... So the question is, how is it usually handled? What's the 'best practice' ?

btw, I am using ruby on rails and carrierwave, if that matters

Comment: You can write a script on the server that will delete all the unused files on the server at a specified time interval.

Comment: yeah, thats what I am thinking about, but maybe somebody can offer something better

Comment: You can add a code that will not allow user to close/quit the browser once the file is uploaded and then delete his/her files on his conformation.

Comment: I think that can be kinda obtrusive

Comment: This is obstructive but it will avoid a situation where a user has closed the browser/tab by mistake. And usually many sites does that when user is in the mid of something and closes the browser/tab then it displays warning to the user for conformation...

Comment: yeah, proably you're right, I'll try to do that and see how it looks, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from running a websocket script (to check when the user closes the browser), I feel the most efficient way to do this is to run a [scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285717/a-cron-job-for-rails-best-practices)

**Images**

It will all hinge on how you'll associate your images with resources on your server. For example, if the images are meant to be used in a piece of content (which is not saved), you can check for the existence of the content, and delete any image which has no association

Like many software systems, the "best practice" will only become apparent if you detail some context to your query. For example -- what are the images for & how will they be managed?

Comment: Looks like scheduled task it is, just as I thought, thank you